# How to make scrollview scroll from first page after it reaches last image?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, scrollview

I have created a auto scroll banner using scrollview in my application. There are 3 images added to scrollview, so I want when scroll reaches the last image it should start from first image and continue scrolling and this process should be repeated.

Right now what is happening is after it reaches the last image, scrollview stops scrolling.

Following is my code:

```
    func setUpScrollView() {
        let numberOfViews : Int = 3;
        for i in 0...numberOfViews-1{
            let origin = CGFloat(i) * (self.view?.frame.size.width)!
            let height : CGFloat
            height = (self.bannerScrollView?.frame.size.height)!

            let image : UIImageView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(x : origin,y : 0.0,width : (self.view?.frame.size.width)!,height : height))
            image.image = UIImage.init(named: String.init(format: "banner%d", i+1))
            image.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
            self.bannerScrollView?.addSubview(image)

        }
        self.bannerScrollView?.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(numberOfViews), height: (self.bannerScrollView?.frame.size.height)!)
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(autoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        self.pageControl = UIPageControl.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.pageControl?.numberOfPages = 3
        self.pageControl?.isEnabled = false
        self.bannerScrollView?.addSubview(self.pageControl!)        
    }


 func autoScroll() {
                let targetXOffset = (self.bannerScrollView?.contentOffset.x)! + (self.bannerScrollView?.bounds.size.width)!

                if targetXOffset <= CGFloat(((self.bannerScrollView?.contentSize.width)! - (self.bannerScrollView?.bounds.size.width)!)) {
                    self.bannerScrollView?.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: targetXOffset,y: 0), animated: true)
                }

                let width : CGFloat = (self.bannerScrollView?.frame.size.width)!
                let page = ((self.bannerScrollView?.contentOffset.x)! + width)/width        
}
```

Comment: you can try using carousel view for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
func autoScroll() {
    guard let scrollView = bannerScrollView else { return }
    let width: CGFloat = scrollView.bounds.width
    let targetXOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x + width

    if targetXOffset <= CGFloat((scrollView.contentSize.width - width)) {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: targetXOffset, y: 0), animated: true)
    } else {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
    }

    let page = (scrollView.contentOffset.x + width)/width  
    //need to do something with this page value      
}
```

Be careful with all those `!` - they are waiting to blow up on you

Comment: This created the effect of scrolling back to the start when the end is reached, I believe the question is looking for an "infinite" scrolling solution, where it just keeps scrolling in the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is simply simulate an infinite scrolling experience.

You want to duplicate your first image to the end of the scrollview so you now have 4 images, where the first and the last match.

When you begin your auto scroll, you check if you are on this repeated 4th page. If you are, you set the content offset back to `(0, 0)` with no animation (this is not apparent to the user since they are the same) and then simply animate on to the second image, and repeat.